# Registering KryoSerializer to Hazelcast

Tags: serialization, hazelcast, kryo

I created a serializer for a specific object using the `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer` (extending from it and passing my generic parameter).
Now i want to put my object into a `com.hazelcast.map.IMap` by setting the value type to my custom object.

My question is, how do i tell my `com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance` that it should use my custom kryo serializer for serialization of the object?

I am also using https://github.com/jerrinot/subzero in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation here for Kryo, JSON or other customer serializers to use with Hazelcast: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.1.1/manual/html-single/index.html#custom-serialization

Comment: I already tried serializing by using the StreamSerializer, that works perfectly fine. But it does not serializes the attributes of an other Object